# How many ways to choose a set of tulips given some conditions

Tags: combinatorics

There are four different colors of tulips grown on large fields near Eindhoven, The Netherlands: yellow, orange, purple, and amber. Old Flemish superstition has that if a young boy gives a bouquet of tulips to a young girl, then the number of tulips of color whose name starts with a vowel must be odd, while the number of those, whose color name starts with a consonant must be even respectively for each color, otherwise the girl would never get into love with the boy. How many ways can a young boy choose $n$ tulips if he regards the superstition?

Is the solution to the problem just finding the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x^2+x^4 + \cdots)^2(x+x^3 + x^5 + \cdots)^2$?

Comment: Do you consider y a vowel?  Are $n$ and $k$ supposed to be the same?

Comment: @Millikan Sorry, yes $n$ and $k$ are the same and I have changed it to reflect that. And, I am not considering y to be a vowel in this case.

Comment: The Flemish are still quite distant from Eindhoven, only Brabantish people live there.... Why would the Flemish care about Brabantish flowers anyway? :)

Comment: If you're interested, this problem has enough structure to be solved in closed form: Pick $1$ each of orange and amber, and then for the remaining $n-2$ consider them as ${n-2 \over 2}$ pairs.  So you're asking how many ways to fill ${n-2 \over 2}$ indistinguishable boxes with balls of $4$ colors, which can be solved with the standard stars and bars method.

Comment: @antkam:  as I read the problem the parity of each color of tulip has to be correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan - yeah, and in my solution, after the initial orange and amber, all flowers come in pairs, so orange and amber are necessarily odd and yellow and purple are necessarily event.  or am i missing something?

Comment: I had missed the divide by $2$.  That is a good answer.  You should post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested, this problem has enough structure to be solved in closed form:

Pick $1$ each of orange and amber, and then for the remaining $n−2$ flowers consider them as ${n−2 \over 2}$ pairs.  For each pair now choose a color.  You will end up with an even number of yellows and purples (since they come in pairs), and an odd number of oranges and ambers (due to the initial $1$ flower for each color).

The number of ways to assign $4$ colors to $k={n-2 \over 2}$ indistinguishable pairs can be solved by the classic stars and bars method.  The answer is ${k+4 - 1 \choose 4-1} = {{n-2 \over 2} + 3 \choose 3}$.

BTW this answer was inspired by this observation:

$$
\begin{align}
 (1+x^2+x^4 + \cdots)^2(x+x^3 + x^5 + \cdots)^2 &= (1+x^2+x^4 + \cdots)^2 (x (1+x^2+x^4 + \cdots))^2 \\
&= x^2 (1+x^2+x^4 + \cdots)^4
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you consider $y$ a consonant, you are correct.

If $y$ is a vowel, it should be the coefficient of $n$ in  $$(1+x^2+x^4 + \cdots)(x+x^3 + x^5 + \cdots)^3$$ because there are three vowels and one consonant.

Comment: One question. Does the fact that orange and amber tulips must be odd mean that we cannot have zero of them? So in all cases we must have at least one amber and one orange tulip?

Comment: @Wesley seems that way, yes.